# Is if(!$someObject) equivalent to if($someObject!==null)?

Tags: php

Are these two expressions equivalent? If they are, can you explain why? (I am a java programmer):

```
if(!$someObject)

if($someObject!==null)
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that variables in PHP need to start with a `$`.

Comment: FYI, the short answer is "no" which none of these answers come right out and say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a look a the [type comparisons table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) on php.net

Plus in your case, if `$someObject = true`, then  `if($someObject!==null)` works but `if(!$someObject)` won't.

In PHP you have the two different type of comparison, the loose one (`==`, `!=`) and the strict one (`===`, `!==`).
`if` works with a loose comparison.
The second `if` you use will *basically* work with strict comparison, so the two of them *can't* be equivalent.

The only way to have a real equivalent is to work with the same comparison "type" within the two if.

---

`if(!$someObject)` is equivalent to `if($someObject == false)` only.

Answer (score 2):

$someObject!==null is more restrictive comparing to !$someObject,
!$someObject would return true if $someObject is not null,'', false or 0

Answer (score 2):

by using an expression such as (!variable) matches the main negatives such as `null,false,0`

any variable with these values would return `true` using the exclamation operator. and false without.

im sure you know your data-types such as `booleons,strings,ints,doubles/floats` but im not sure you understand how logical operators work within php, ill give you shour example.

```
$a = $b; //This would assign $b to $a, a single = is an assignment operator. 
$a == $b; //this is a value comarison operator, iot matches the VALUE not the type.
$a === $b; //This is a VALUE & TYPE Comparison, this would batch the value and data-types
```

Theres a few other expressions you can use such as:

```
$a != $b; //This is negative version to the second expression above - the ==,
$a !== $b; //this is a negative VALUE & TYPE comparison - the ===
```

Take a look here for more in-depth examples.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so to figure out why, let's create a truth table for the first if statement.

`!{statement}` basically is the same as saying `{statement} != false`.  Now, considering that `{statement}` in this case is a variable, it will be equivalent (`==`) to false for all of these conditions (considering the loose typing, so all of these are equivalent to `false` for a `==` test):

1. `0`
2. `'0'`
3. `''`
4. `null`
5. `false`
6. `array()`

So if the `{statement}` is equal to any of those cases, the statement `!{statement}` will be true (and hence the if executed)

Now, the second comparison is basically asking if `{statement}` is not identical (in both value and type, which is how the `!==` differs from `!=`) to `null`.  Since `null` is special, the only time the second if will not pass is if `{statement}` is exactly `null`.

So no, they are not interchangeable yet alone equivalent.  The first has a lot of cases when the if will be executed, and the second has only one when it will not be...

Answer (score -1):

`if (!someObject)` equal `if (!isset(someObject))`

Comment: -1 `isset` has nothing to do with a boolean test.  Sure, if the variable is not set, trying to use it will generate a null (and hence `!null` is true), but it's no where's near equal to `!$var`...  And @Colin: Not if `$someObject` is `0`, `'0'`, `''`, `false`, `array()` either...

Comment: isset is to check the state of the variable, not the state of the data-type / value, example `$a = false; var_dump(isset($a));` would be true.